# The approximation of first-ordered modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: bessel-functions

After analysing the outage probability of a single relay selection system, I got to the following form:
$P = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\left( \begin{array}{l}
K\\
k
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}2\sqrt {\frac{{k{\gamma _o}{c_p}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}{\lambda _{RD}}}}} {e^{ - \frac{{k{\gamma _o}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}}}}}{K_1}\left( {2\sqrt {\frac{{k{\gamma _o}{c_p}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}{\lambda _{RD}}}}} } \right)}$. When $\lambda_{SR}$ and $\lambda_{RD}$ go to infinity we can use the approximation: ${K_1}\left( x \right) \sim \frac{1}{x}$ (where ${K_1}\left( x \right)$ is the first-ordered modified Bessel function of the second kind) to get an asymptotic of the above formula to be:
$P = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\left( \begin{array}{l}
K\\
k
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{e^{ - \frac{{k{\gamma _o}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}}}}}}$. However, the original and the approximation forms are not closed when $\lambda_{SR}$ and $\lambda_{RD}$ go to infinity. Here is the test figure:[image]

Can somebody give me some hint how these form behave like that?
Thank you very much.
Best Regards, Binh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approximate expression is just a binomial expansion of $(1-e^{-\gamma_0/\lambda_{SR}})^K$, so it decays as $\lambda_{SR}^{-K}$.  The exact expression contains other terms in the expansion of the Bessel function

$${\rm K}_1(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{4}\left(2\ln\frac{x}{2}+2\gamma-1\right)+{\rm O}(x^3\ln x)$$

which do not cancel as nicely from the alternating signs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please tell me where you get the above formula for $K_1(x)$?
Thank you.

Comment: I used mathematica.  It should be possible to derive this from the relevant formulae at dlmf.nist.gov